# db2pd: Database mydb not activated on partition 0

Tags: db2, windows

As a user with `DBADM` privileges I enter

```
db2pd -db mydb -locks showdetail
```

from the DB2 CLP. The command then fails with message

```
Database mydb not activated on database partition 0.

Option -locks requires -db <database> or -alldbs option and active database.
```

I verified that the database is active:

```
C:\Windows\system32>db2 list active databases

                           Active Databases

Database name                              = MYDB
Applications connected currently           = 0
Database path                              = C:\DB2\NODE0000\SQL00002\
```

I also googled the error message and found an [IBM support page for TSM](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21399269) which suggests my environment variable `%db2instance%` might not be set appropriately. However, everything appears to be in order:

```
C:\Windows\system32>set %db2instance%
DB2CLP=DB20FADE
DB2INSTANCE=DB2
DB2PATH=C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB
```

What other reasons could there be, that `db2pd` is giving me the above error message?

I'm running DB2 v9.7.4 on Windows 7 Embedded.

Comment: Does your login ID have the local administrator authority on the DB2 server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`db2pd` requires Administrator authority on Windows, *in the command shell you are executing it*.  Setting your ID as a member of the Administrators group on the local machine is not sufficient.

IBM adds "DB2 Command Window - Administrator" in your Start Menu to give you a DB2 Command Window that has administrator privileges (which is the recommended method).  Alternatively if you are using a normal command window (cmd.exe), you would have to start it by right clicking "Command Prompt" and choosing "Run as Administrator".

It *might* be possible to use `runas` to execute `db2pd`, but it's probably easier to just start the command window directly with administrator privileges.

Comment: If I am a local admin, does not _any_ shell (or any program, for that matter) run for me with admin authorities?

Comment: No, it's not like logging in to a UNIX box as root.  You have to specify to start something with admin authority, at which point Windows pops up the UAC dialog.

Comment: That did solve my problem, thank you very much. The user under which I was executing `db2pd` had `DBADM` privilege which I believed would suffice, but it was not part of the Administrators group of Windows. Adding the user to the Administrators group and starting `db2cmd` via right click -> Run as Administrator then worked.